# Should this question really be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[What units, if any, were removed or restricted from Heart of the Swarm multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108571/what-units-if-any-were-removed-or-restricted-from-heart-of-the-swarm-multiplay)

was marked as a duplicate of

[What balance changes were made between the final Wings of Liberty Patch and Heart of the Swarm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106193/what-balance-changes-were-made-between-the-final-wings-of-liberty-patch-and-hear)

The first asks for **balance changes to existing units in multiplayer**, and the second (duplicate) asks which units are **restricted from play in multiplayer** (i.e. only appear in Single-player, or custom maps).

Now on first glance, the questions are similar, but on closer inspection they are quite different, and will garner very different answers (in my opinion). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only units that would have been removed or restricted from HotS Multiplayer were units from Wings of Liberty.

If they had intended to ask what units are single-player only, they *should have asked that*, as the question explicitly mentions multiplayer. In the original question, emphasis mine:

> During development of Heart of the Swarm, there were several mentions
>   (e.g. the Thor, Carrier, and Mothership) of units being removed (or
>   restricted to 1) **in HOTS multiplayer (compared to Wings of Liberty
>   multiplayer).**

If you wish to ask a question about what single-player campaign units are not available in multiplayer, go ahead and do so, but such a question is unlikely to solicit useful discussion, and I expect it will be summarily downvoted and/or closed. Very few campaign missions play exactly like multiplayer missions, and (I find) there is little use in comparing the two of them by units.

Comment: I didn't ask the dupe question, I just thought it was different enough to warrant intervention (so don't get all uppity :P). However, I must have missed the part you've bolded here. You're correct, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Apologies, @Robotnik, no uppity-ness intended! I've closed a lot of questions as dupes today, and my nerves are starting to fray. ♪

Comment: No apologies needed, it happens to the best of us :). Thanks again for taking time to clarify this, I know how busy you guys get.